# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'sendTransaction')

Tags: solidity, hardhat

I am trying to mint a ERC-20 token here. I have compiled the smart contract. While trying to run I get this error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'sendTransaction')

Token.sol:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract DevToken is ERC20{
    constructor(uint256 totalSupply) ERC20("Gabby", "GB"){
        _mint(msg.sender, totalSupply);
    }
}
```

deploy.js

```
const hre = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  const DevToken = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("DevToken");
  const devToken = await DevToken.deploy("1000000000000000000000000000");

  await devToken.deployed();

  console.log("Token deployed to:", devToken.address);
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your config file. Your code is working fine at my end :)

Comment: Yes had issue with the url in hardhat.config.js . Thank you